# How to force recheck torrents in ktorrent (Kubuntu)?

Tags: kubuntu, bittorrent, torrent-client, ktorrent

I have found options in bit torrent (for windows) for force rechecking the torrent downloads. But could not find any option in ktorrent client on Kubuntu. Couldn't find any from other sources. Does someone know a method to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Go to **Settings** > **BitTorrent**

Under **Features**, check the box next to **Check data when download is finished**.